# Irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I have the polynomial $X^2+Y^2-1$ in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$.

> Is this irreducible? If not, how do I factorize it?

Should I handle this the same as if it were $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$, or should I do it differently?

Comment: You can use Eisenstein.

Comment: @T.S.L. Which prime element could I use for Eisenstein?

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = x^2 + (y+1)(y-1) \in \mathbf{C}[y][x]$

Comment: @T.S.L. So the prime element is either $y-1$ or $y+1$?

Comment: Those are prime because they're irreducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R$ be a UFD of characteristic $\neq 2$. Then $X^2+Y^2-1 \in R[Y][X]$ has no root in $R[Y]$. Indeed, a root $P \in R[Y]$ would satisfy $P^2=1-Y^2=(1+Y)(1-Y)$, which is impossible since $1+Y$ and $1-Y$ are non-associated prime elements in $R[Y]$. Thus, $X^2+Y^2-1$ is irreducible in $R[Y][X]$, being a polynomial of degree less than $4$.

Comment: I'm afraid I dont fully understand what youre doing here. Why would $P$ satisfy that? And why is it impossible to satisfy that?

Comment: Because $P$ being a root of $X^2 + Y^2 -1$, considered as a polynomial in $(R[Y])[X]$, means $P^2+Y^2-1=0$. But, since $1+Y$ and $1-Y$ are non-associated prime elements, this is not possible (due to uniqueness of factorization. A factorization of $P$ gives a factorization of $P^2$; in particular the powers of the factors appearing in the factorization of $P^2$ must be even).